# increment text input on modal returning 1,3,6,10,15

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

Trying to implement an autoincrement function on a modal form with text inputs on top of a Goggle map.

The problemn is that my text field adds up all the sums of the values, so that I get the following incremented values when my field starts with a value = '0': 1,3,6,10,15,21,28,... 
I just want to have a simple increment by 1: 1,2,3,4,5,...

Here how my code looks like:

HTML input on modal form

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num" value='0'>
```

Part of JS displaying Google Maps Api v3

```
       //Add listener to map, to insert new Marker with modal
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(event){
      marker = new MarkerWithLabel ({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map,
          icon:mmcross,
          draggable: true,
            labelContent: '',
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground: false
        });

      map.setCenter(event.latLng);

          //Open Modal Form to insert data
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
          $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
             $("#num").get(0).value++
          });                   
      });

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had to remove the second $('#myModal') call to get it work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
   $(function() {
       $("#num").get(0).value++                  
  });
});
```